# How can you plot a subfunction in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I can't figure out how to plot a subfunction of my program using plot.

```
main() 
...
    % this works 
    fplot('4 * (x^-12 - x^-6)', [0.98,2]);
    % these and other combinations don't work
    fplot('potential', [0.98,2]);
    fplot('potential(x)', [0.98,2]);
    plot(0.98:0.01:2, potential(x));
end

function v = potential(x)
   v = 4 * (x^-12 - x^-6);
end
```

Could you please shed some light on how you should use plot to plot a subfunction if you don't want to write all of it. I'm sure I'll run into this problem again.

Comment: Explain how the other combinations don't work, in detail, with error messages if any, in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you don't want to write all of it"?

Comment: Also, did you mean `0.01` instead of `00.1`?

Comment: `fplot(@potential,[0.98,2]);`

Comment: I just get empty plots on the other variants. Yes, I meant 0.01, sorry I will correct that. @Mad Physicist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a string to a function like `fplot` (or `ode45` for that matter) will more than likely not work for local or nested functions since they will most likely leverage a function like [`str2func`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) or [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html).  In both cases, the context in which the local or nested function is defined is hidden from `fplot` and `ode45`, and the function will not be found since it is not on the MATLAB the path.

The way to avoid this problem is to almost always use function handles.  Function handles will bind the appropriate context data and everything will work as intended.  Consider this example that will print the meta-information provided by the creation of the handle:

```
function [] = main() 
    potfun = @potential;
    fplot(potfun, [0.98,2]);

    %   To see more clearly what information the handle has:
    functions(potfun)
end
function v = potential(x)
   v = 4 * (x.^-12 - x.^-6);
end
```

(I also switched to element-wise exponent operators, which is almost always a good idea.)

This prints the following struct from [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html):

```
>> main
ans = 
     function: 'potential'
         type: 'scopedfunction'
         file: 'C:\main.m'
    parentage: {'potential'  'main'}
```

As can be seen, the full needed context to call the subfunction ("scopefunction" apparently) from other functions is provided.

Answer (score 0):

use `arrayfun`:

```
x = 0.98:00.1:2;
y = arrayfun(@(x)4 * (x^-12 - x^-6),x); 
% or y = arrayfun(@(x)potential(x),x)
plot(x,y);
```

Or if the step is not important use the following code:

```
fplot(@(x)potential(x), [0.98, 2])
```

Comment: `arrayfun` is a bit of overkill here, no?